# The things affecting operation of a transformer

Tags: transformer

While using transformers, is it only the winding ratio that matters?

I cannot understand one point that the voltage between primary cables of a transformer is very low when I measure. It is logical because it is just cables. But then how do we refer primary voltage for example 220 Volts ? And also how does the frequency of the signal affects the working of the transformer? I tried like a frequency sweep between almos 0.5 Hz to 150kHz (i hope did not harm the transformer) by hand but could not catch a pattern.

The thing is actually are the transformers as simple as Vs = Ns/Np * Vp ?

Comment: Try googling transformers and studying leakage inductance, magnetization inductance, eddy currents, copper loss and core losses. Then things aint so simple.

Answer (score 0):

From experience, I note that the ratio of windings determines the limiting case assuming perfect efficiency.  When dealing with real currents and frequencies, the mass of the core and its magnetic properties add limits.
A small transformer will have a severe voltage drop if you demand a high current.  Usually, the transformer's rated voltage is specified at its rated current.
Different cores (ferrite vs soft iron, etc) are efficient at different frequencies, so iron cores are useful at 50/60hZ while ferrites and specialty materials are used at high frequencies.